# Failed to import Gradle project error creating new project with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

**Version of Android Studio:0.2.5 Build 130.782403, OS version: Windows 7 Pro 64bit, Java JRE/JDK version: 1.7, Android SDK V22.0.5, All updates/Extras are installed**

I randomly get this error when trying to create a new project with Android Studio

> Failed to import Gradle project: Network is unreachable: connect
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

- It sometimes works when I'm not connected to the Internet
- It sometimes doesn't work until I connect to the Internet

I believe the developer should be able to create a new project even if he/she doesn't have an Internet connection.

Comment: Are you using dynamic version with gradle plugin like this :         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+' ? try to use 0.5.6 see if it helps

Comment: No, I don't use dynamic version. and it still not working without Internet connection, the solution i found is to shutdown All Network ports while creating or opening existing/new projects then reopen it again, but this is weird behavior and i'm looking for more explanation, thanks

Comment: how do I shutdown all the ports in windows 8 ?? Please help me, I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with the latest Android Studio () today, and I finally found that configuring a https proxy for Gradle can solve the issue. I only set a http proxy at the beginning.  Gradle needs to sync some files via HTTPS. Use IP address instead if hostname of proxy can't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your android studio go to **Help -> Show log in explorer** then open the file **idea.log** and fetch in this file where is the problem, you gonna find where your android studio try to connect and it couldn't (proxy issues, some server link in your gradle refuse your connexion, non reachable server, no internet access...)